# Stylesheets not linked with https

Tags: html, css, apache2

I have a standard page, with the following code on

```
<head>
    <link href="http://path.to/stylsheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

However when I load the page via https and force https traffic through ReWrite conditions the stylsheet fails to load

Any Ideas?

Thank's in Advance
-C

Comment: Your stylesheet has to be accessible over https as well.

Comment: @Cfreak Thanks! I didn't know this, add this as an answer and I shall accept this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access your stylesheet over HTTPs as well.

```
 <link href="https://path.to/stylsheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

All files in a site must be references as https if you intend to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax below allows your stylesheet to be loaded via whatever protocol your site is accessed through (assuming the stylesheet is accessible via http and https:

```
<link href="//path.to/stylsheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```